# How can i make a Slide Show for my Home Page with the following requirements

Tags: 7, views, theming

How can I make a Slide Show for my Home Page with the following requirements:

1. The image would link to any content
2. The caption would be different for all images of the slide show
3. The slide show would be responsive
4. The images can be added, deleted from the CMS itself by the client/admin
5. Navigation controllers
6. Place a link "Sign Up" on top of the slide show which takes the user to the  sign up page

I tried with Views Nivo slider but it has open issues regarding rewrite results. Are there any other modules? Views slideshow is one but I am not able to configure it as per my exact requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Views slideshow has solutions to be responsive, see:
http://drupal.org/node/1510526

You can also embed a custom slideshow navigation using views and a `global counter` in the view, using Tokens you can replace the counter text with whatever you want. An example of this can be found here:
http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2012/01/03/building-slideshows-with-navigation-based-views

All of your criteria are met by Views Slideshow I believe, you just have to get crazy with CSS. I have made the following slideshow with Views Slideshow using the navigation tutorial above, Views, Views Slideshow and Nodequeue.

**example view slideshow config**
[image: view slideshow config]

**default rendering of ViewsSlideshow in Admin area, an un-themed slideshow**
[image: default Views rendering in Admin, or un-themed view]

**Final themed slideshow with custom navigation**
[image: final slideshow integrated into theme]

In my case I overlay the navigation into the view, I had to use jQuery to achieve some of the dimensions at runtime and CSS3 stuff for opacity of my overlay div.

Answer (score 0):

Read [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/755010) for slideshow. this [tutoral](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-slideshow-in-drupal-7/) may help you. To making responsive slider, see here. [Make views slideshow responsive - remove inline styles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44662/make-views-slideshow-responsive-remove-inline-styles)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module http://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic ,its nothing but the support module for views . You can customize the slideshow with thumbnail,content of slideshow,prev ,next button and pagination through view fields.