# How do I make my homepage slideshow to fit the page width?

Tags: theming, 6, media

I have my website built in Drupal 6, and I have used the Views slideshow module for the home page banner which is 960 pixel wide. I need a banner with 100% width to fit the page. Can anybody help me in making it to 100% or kindly suggest any full width banner slideshow module which is compatible with Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

Is your website wider than 960px ? ... I have you looked at online CSS tutorials such as [Full Screen Background Image Pure CSS Code](http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code), or CSS3 [cover property for background-images as mentioned here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). I think the CSS Only Technique #1 is more what your looking for in your slideshow's inline images.

Anyways, Google will help you alot here. Views Slideshow ships with basic *useable* CSS, but it's not themed for everyones needs. It's up to you to tweak its CSS as you need. As an example I've previously given here -- [taking a Views slideshow and using only css + jquery and changing it to meet client needs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/68024/3279).

Sorry I dont know of a module that just does all the themeing for you, views slideshow does do 99% of the work for you by providing a workable slideshow for your site.

Answer (score 1):

Set the container's width to 100%, remove the maximum width, then set the width of `.views-field-field-slideshow-image img` to 100%.

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? It appears to be the actual correct answer, though it could use more context. Essentially creating a full width anything in Drupal requires modifying an existing theme's stylesheets or creating a new custom theme. There may be existing themes that support a full width views-slideshow, but finding and listing them is beyond the scope of SE.