# How to make the "Height" of Views Slideshow Fully responsive?

Tags: views, theming

I'm working on a slideshow on Drupal 7 with [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). The only issue I have right now is to make the **Frame** "**Height**"(not the image) responsive **when resizing the browser**. I found many articles, questions and answers about how to make Views Slideshow responsive, but none of them work properly. I believe the "Frame" is causing this.

These articles I found does not really fix the height of Views Slideshow. Maybe I missing something.
- [Make views slideshow responsive - remove inline styles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44662/make-views-slideshow-responsive-remove-inline-styles)
- [Can't remove the height/width of the slide container](https://www.drupal.org/node/1146566#comment-9059627)

----- updated for @Patrick Ryan

I got some error from google chrome web browser after adding these js

[image]

----- updated on Aug. 20, 2014 @ 9:46am 
I found the following script also fix the height. Its from drupal.org issue [views Slideshow for Responsive design](https://www.drupal.org/node/1510526) on #26

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.views_slideshow_cycle_main').each(function(){
    var cycleMain = $(this);
    var img_width = 0,
        img_height = 0;
    var clearCSS = {width: "auto", height: "auto"};
    var cycle = cycleMain.children('.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame');
    cycleElements = cycle.data("cycle.opts");
    cycle.css(clearCSS);
    cycleMain.find('.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row').each(function(i){
      $(this).css(clearCSS);
      var tmp_img_width = $(this).width();
      var tmp_img_height = $(this).height();
      if(tmp_img_width > img_width)
        img_width = tmp_img_width;
      if(tmp_img_height > img_height)
        img_height = tmp_img_height;
      cycleElements.elements[i].cycleW = tmp_img_width;
      cycleElements.elements[i].cycleH = tmp_img_height;
      $(this).css({width: tmp_img_width, height: tmp_img_height});
    });
    cycleMain.height(img_height);
    cycle.css({width: img_width, height: img_height});
    cycle.data("cycle.opts.elements", cycleElements);
  });
});
```

Comment: RE: js error - how/where did you add the js?  Try changing `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: i just realize i need to add the "(function($){" before and "})(jQuery);" after your code lol. Now, its working!!! Many thanks @Patrick Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally take care of the height with javascript.  First I make sure that I am handling the width properly with CSS:

```
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame,
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row,
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Then I create a function that sets the height.  This will take whatever container your slideshow is in as a parameter and find the slideshow within it.

```
/* Slideshow resize function */
Drupal.theme.prototype.slideshowResizer = function (target){
  var slideheight = 0;
  $(target + ' .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row').each(function(){
    slideheight = $(this).find('.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item').innerHeight();
    if(slideheight != 0){
      $(target + ' .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame').css('height',slideheight+'px');
      $(target + ' .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row').css('height',slideheight+'px');
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

And finally I call the function on the window resize event:

```
Drupal.behaviors.slideshowResize = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {            
    $('.your-slideshow-container', context).once('processed', function () {
      Drupal.theme('slideshowResizer', '.your-slideshow-container');
    });

    $(window).resize( function() {
      Drupal.theme('slideshowResizer', '.your-slideshow-container');
    });         
  }
};
```

Also, make sure your base img tag has `height: auto;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I adding the first js on .info. where should I add the calling function?

Comment: Both function and calling the function can be in the same JS document.  I usually just drop them into my main JS file.

Comment: tried few times still dont know what should i replace with ".your-slideshow-container". :(

Comment: If your slideshow is in a block, you can use the blocks class.  Or you can use any selector that wraps around `.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row`.

Comment: hmmm.... i replacing it with ".views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame", which is the container. Nothing happen on the slideshow but my theme changed.

Comment: It won't work on `.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame`.  You need to go up another step and use the block class or the outermost container.

Comment: not sure what happen, but it does not work on my Drupal. I tried ".view-main-slideshow", "#block-views-main-slideshow-block-1", and event the region lol. this is what happen. something looks simple but never is.

Comment: Do you have any JS errors?  Are you 100% certain that this JS is being loaded?  It's pretty straightforward, the only reason it wouldn't work is JS errors or your JS isn't loaded.

Comment: I got some error from Google Chrome adding these js. please see my updated post above.

Comment: This worked for me.

I used .views_slideshow_cycle_main for .your-slideshow-container.

I created a custom JS file in the theme folder and imported it from within the .info file for the theme by adding this line:

scripts[] = js/views-slideshow-responsive.js (this is the name and location of the JS file I created).

I also made sure the code in the file was declared correctly, per this post: [https://www.drupal.org/node/1003664#comment-4414248. I was getting a JS error prior to that.

Comment: One further comment and a small potential gotcha. I'm using the Picture module to display different versions of the images at different break points. This solution still works, but there are some occasions when manually resizing the window causes the images to either overlap other elements on the page, or to leave empty space between the image and other elements adjacent to it.